# How Cron Job Works?

Tags: python, visual-studio, cron

From last few days I was looking for a method to restart my script on a particular time. That's when I got introduced to  Cron Job. I came through a link

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-cron#jobs-

which states that how to use use cron job in settings.json file. I have downloaded the extension in visual studio and also specified the location of file with the command.
I have made a code: -

```
{
    
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    
    
        "cron.jobs": {
            "jobs": [
                {
                   
                    "name": "Rebooting the software",
                    "description": "Rebooting the software three times in a day.",
                    
                    "time": "0,0,17 0,12,10 * * * * *",
                    "action": {
                        "type": "command",
                        "command": "/home/pi/Schreibtisch/PSTecSoftware/AccessControlRepository/AccessControl/DevicesWrapper.py.extension.cronJons.restartRunningJobs"
                        
                    }
                    

                    }
            ]
            }
    
    

}
```

its not working I really have no idea what changes should I make to get it working.

Comment: do you want visualstudio to run your python script periodically?

Comment: @balderman I want to restart a particular script at a particular time daily.which is DevicesWrapper.py in this case.

Comment: The code - should it run on Linux or Windows?

Comment: on a remote raspberry pi device using visual studio raspian.

Comment: see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Comment: But then I have to do it for every raspberry pi individually but I want cron job should be applied to every raspberry pi when my code is deployed as a package to the raspberry pi.